# Angular UI Bootstrap datepicker malfunctioning

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using [Angular Ui Datepicker](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker) in my app. Strange thing is happening, may be a bug. The date picker is not functioning (not showing) if there is a child element inside the datepicker element.

In my example below if I put span (or any other) tag inside `a` tag - where I have put my datepicker - it will not work, but if there is not child element inside of it , it works as expected.

Is this a bug or I am missing something ?

**Edit** : [Created A Fiddle Also](http://jsfiddle.net/lekhnath/fsfs3e9L/2/)

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller("TestController", function($scope) {
  $scope.isOpen = false;
  $scope.isOpen2 = false;
  $scope.isOpen3 = false;

  $scope.popupOptions = {};
});
```

```html
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div ng-app="app">
  <a href="javascript://" ng-model="deadline" is-open="isOpen" ng-click="isOpen = !isOpen" datepicker-popup="popupOptions"> This will show Date picker </a>
  <br />
  <a href="javascript://" ng-model="deadline2" is-open="isOpen2" ng-click="isOpen2 = !isOpen2" datepicker-popup="popupOptions"> <span> This will not </span> 
  </a>
  <br />

  <a href="javascript://"> <span ng-model="deadline2" is-open="isOpen3" datepicker-popup="popupOptions" ng-click="isOpen3 = !isOpen3"> This will also show  </span> 
  </a>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.12.0/ui-bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.12.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I have opened issue here : https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/3076

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the datepicker can only be set on the innermost elements. It might be that way by design as I found no examples where datepicker is set on a parent element.

Also, you code works if the datepicker is set on span(or any other child element).

```
<a href="javascript://">
    <span ng-model="deadline" is-open="isOpen" ng-click="isOpen = !isOpen" datepicker-popup="popupOptions">datepicker set on span inside anchor</span>
</a>
```

[Plnkr](http://jsfiddle.net/dx1xobds/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example to use the directive with a bootstrap input, displaying a calendar button

> **HTML**

```
<p class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" datetime-picker="dd MMM yyyy HH:mm" ng-model="myDate" is-open="isOpen"  />
    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="openCalendar($event, prop)"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></button>
    </span>
</p>
```

> **JAVASCRIPT**

```
app.controller('MyController', function() {
    var that = this;

    this.isOpen = false;

    this.openCalendar = function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();

        that.isOpen = true;
    };
});
```

See demo : https://github.com/Gillardo/bootstrap-ui-datetime-picker